# Robolectric hanging in some instances with Android databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, robolectric

I've already raised an [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/4027) for Robolectric, but have had no response there, so perhaps SO can help me. We've a large app that uses Android Data Binding, and it currently on the rather old `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3`. We have Robolectric 3.8 tests that currently all work ok. We want to upgrade to a modern `com.android.tools.build:gradle` but when we do, some of our tests start to hang. There seems to be a particular way we're using data binding that is causing this, but outside of Robolectric it's all working ok. I've created a stripped-down sample app that shows the same issue, which is [here](https://github.com/jonathan-caryl/RobolectricDatabindingHang). As there's a lot of magic that happens as part of Robolectric, and a lot of magic that happens as part of Data Binding, it makes it particularly hard to follow exactly what's going wrong. Help!

Answer (score 2):

This is super hacky, sorry. You're running into some issues with Robolectric's simplified threading model, which we're working on for 4.1.

Meanwhile, this should work:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    final ActivityController<MainActivity> activityController = buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
    Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().pause();
    activityController.setup();
    Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().advanceToLastPostedRunnable();
    Robolectric.getForegroundThreadScheduler().unPause();
}
```

Comment: As i said on the issue, it works for me! The bounty is yours.